# Is there a way to easily parse file paths in portable class libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, file, path, portable-class-library

I'm needing to parse a path into parts from within a portable class library and get things like the filename, extension, just directory name, etc.

All of these methods are fairly easy to access from within System.IO.Path, however, this doesn't seem to exist within portable class libraries. Is there an open source replacement for this or some other API that would give me the same functionality?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the required target platforms of your PCL. Just in case you don't need to target Silverlight and WP7/8,  `System.IO.Path` would be available if you restrict the target platforms of your PCL to `.NET Framework` and `.NET for Windows Store apps`.

Answer (score 5):

You may be able to use or adapt the code for System.IO.Path from Mono: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs

EDIT: Also, my [PCL Storage](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) library provides some file IO APIs to PCLs, including `PortablePath.Combine()`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Uri` class

```
var segments = new Uri("file://c:/dir1/dir2/a.txt").Segments
```

which is supported by PCL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx