# How does one create a directory with a PCL

Tags: c#, .net, mono, portable-class-library

While dealing with creating a Portable Class Library out of current code for a project, some workarounds are fairly obvious and some are problematic.

`System.IO.Directory` is non-PCL and I still need to be able to create a directory before creating files inside them.

How do you create a folder in C# without being able to call `Directory.CreateDirectory(..)`?

Comment: Have you tried dropping a file into a new directory and seeing what happens?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589795/is-there-a-way-to-easily-parse-file-paths-in-portable-class-libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in file and directory I/O support in PCL, since this functionality differs from platform to platform. However, to circumvent this issue you could reference [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage) in your portable class library project.

*PCLStorage* provides a portable abstraction layer library for file and directory I/O that you would reference in your portable class library. In your platform-specific application implementation, you would incorporate the corresponding *implementation* library of this abstraction layer.

*PCLStorage* is applicable to *.NET Framework 4* and higher, *Silverlight 4* and higher, *Windows Phone 7.5* and higher, and *Windows Store apps*. It relies on `async` and `await`, which means that it is dependent on the [BCL Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx) package when used e.g. with .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone 7.5.

You might also want to have a look at the [MvvmCross](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross) [File plug-in](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/File). *MvvmCross* is portable "by nature" and the *File* plug-in provides relevant file and directory I/O functionality as synchronous methods. *MvvmCross* portable libraries are currently applicable to *.NET Framework 4.5*, *Silverlight 4* and higher, *Windows Phone 7.5* and higher, *Windows Store apps*, *Xamarin.iOS* and *Xamarin.Android*.