# Portable Class Library does not support System.IO, Why?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I created a **portable class library** to be used in my **Monodroid project**.
But the problem is that I need **System.IO** library but unfortunately I couldn't add it.

I even tried to add it by Add Reference option but it was in vain.

Why this happened ?
How shall I do this ?

Comment: Seems like Yuval answer is more detailed than mine. so I'll leave this as a comment: It's not there. You can have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15033175/1698987) that suggest a work around, and points to [this project](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs) that might help you further).

Comment: Why? Because the api's you are looking for don't exist on all the platforms in your current portable profile - eg not on silverlight, on silverlight for windows phone, on windows runtime for win 8 or win phone 8.1, etc. one workaround to try is https://pclstorage.codeplex.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't use `System.IO` because it isn't a portable class library. `System.IO` makes calls which are specific to the OS it runs on (Windows), while the portable class library is ment to be cross-platform.

The solution to what you're looking for can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx):

> What should you do when you’re trying to write a portable library but
>   you need some functionality that isn’t supported?  You can’t call the
>   API directly, and you can’t reference a library that does, because
>   portable libraries can’t reference non-portable libraries.  The
>   solution is to create an abstraction in your portable library that
>   provides the functionality you need, and to implement that abstraction
>   for each platform your portable library targets.  For example, if you
>   need to save and load text files, you might use an interface like
>   this:

```
public interface IFileStorage 
{
    Task SaveFileAsync(string filename, string contents);
    Task<String> LoadFileAsync(string filename); 
}
```

> It’s a good idea to include only the functionality you need in the
>   abstraction.  In this example, the interface doesn’t abstract general
>   file system concepts such as streams, folders, or enumerating files. 
>   This makes the abstraction more portable and easier to implement.  The
>   methods return Tasks so that the implementation for Windows Store apps
>   can call the WinRT file IO APIs, which are async.
>
> Creating an abstraction allows portable libraries to call into
>   non-portable code, and this pattern is applicable almost any time you
>   need to access non-portable functionality from a portable library.  Of
>   course, you need some way for the portable code to get a reference to
>   an implementation of the abstraction.  How you do that can depend on
>   whether you are writing a cross platform app or a general purpose
>   reusable library.

Comment: I recommend reading the source and checking out the example project. I gathered a lot of useful information from that beyond the standard, especially on how to implement it.