# Class Library System.IO.File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am building a Visual Studio 2015 C# class library project. Apparently System.IO.File is no longer available.
What steps has other developers taken to work around this?
Am I looking in the wrong location?
Has the FILE library functionality been totally removed and now I need to download a package?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.IO; 
namespace Framework.File 
{ 
    public class UTL 
    { 
        public bool Read() 
        { 
            try 
            {
                using (StreamReader fileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(Name)) 
    . . . . .
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add an assembly to a Visual Studio project and reference it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157133/how-do-i-add-an-assembly-to-a-visual-studio-project-and-reference-it)

Comment: Is this a PCL project?

Comment: Would you provide the whole block of code?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Framework.File
{
    public class UTL
    {
        public bool Read()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader fileReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(Name))
                {

Comment: @RussellZipoff can you answer if this is a PCL project or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Portable Class Library does not support System.IO, Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460581/portable-class-library-does-not-support-system-io-why)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the using statement and make sure you have the System dll under references.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        private StreamReader _sr = System.IO.File.OpenText("c://temp//boom.text");
    }
}
```

It is still there.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io(v=vs.110).aspx
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,1c7421e464f67b7e

[image: References]

Comment: I have the following usings:

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

Comment: But I am getting this nasty error:  CS0234 The type or namespace name 'File' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Framework..NET Platform

Comment: Make sure you have those two under references.